# How to insert a value at given index or indices ( mutiple index ) into a Tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

I am having a matrix of size 12 x 10 and a list of document_length = [4,3,5] . The first 4 rows belongs to sentences of one document, next 3 to other doc and last 5 to other doc. I need to get a new matrix or Tensor of size 15 x 10 in  the following manner.

I need to insert a row of zeros, in such a way that, here max doc length is 5. So, 1 row of zero has to be inserted in 5th index ( because first doc length is 4 ) . Then 2 row of zeros at index 9 and 10 ( second doc length is 3 ) and so on . If the question is confusing please let me know .

I have feed 12 x 10 to GRU or LSTM , but it has to be in a 3d . To get a proper 3D, I need to convert 12 X 10 to 15 x 10 . Any help ?

Comment: Are your matrices loaded in the numpy format?

Comment: @martianwars - Actually the 12x10 is obtaining from a LSTM. The output is 12x10 numpy array. But, as it is a Tensor inside, numpy indexing cannot be used.

Comment: You probably need to `tf.unpack()` the tensor and then insert in the list before a final `tf.pack()`. TF doesn;t seem to have an `insert` function

Comment: sorry use `stack`/`unstack` as `pack` is deprecated

Comment: @martianwars - Was trying many many things, but couldn't get it work. let me check stack / unstack

Comment: I'm adding an answer with code shortly

Comment: @martianwars - Yeah thanks alot, in the mean time, i will try your suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to do it. You first break down your 12x10 Tensor into a list of size 12. This is done using the `tf.unstack()` function.

```
# Assume `words` is my 12x10 tensor
tensors = tf.unstack(words, 12, axis=0)
```

After that, you can insert `tf.zeros()` tensors into the list at your indices. Here for simplicity, I will just insert a tensor in index `4`.

```
b = tf.zeros((10))
tensors.insert(4, b)
```

Finally, `tf.stack()` your list to re-construct it.

```
words = tf.stack(tensors, axis=0)
```

Comment: How to insert the zeros into the tensor. I am updating my tensorflow, because my version is bit older

Comment: i will check and tick your answer. If any more doubts, we can make the thread open for a whil. Thanks

Comment: Also, if you are using an older version (like in my case, 0.11) replace `stack()` with `pack()`

Comment: This is working . But a small problem , I am having several indices to insert into. tensors.insert will accept only integers. Do I have to use a tf.while loop to achieve it  ?

Comment: Why do you need to use tensorflow functions? This is a python list :) a simple loop should do

Comment: Yeah I think so. Thanks.